# Ruby and Rmagick. How to add ImageList to ImageList? Creating list of the lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

I am using Rmagick and Ruby 2.1.0

I have the following code:

```
@ilg = Magick::ImageList.new
@il = Magick::ImageList.new

# in the loop
_______________
pic = Magick::Image.read("#{@dir}/#{e}").first
@il.push(pic)
_______________

@ilg.push(@il.append(false))
@ilg.write("#{@dir}/results/result#{@counter}.jpg")
```

I would like to replace 'pic' variable with Another ImageList.

I need something like this instead of @il.push(pic):

```
@il.push(@another_list.append(true))
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Since the `ImageList` class includes `Enumerable`, to append an image list to the end of the current one, use `:concat` method.

Comment: Many thanks, I will try concat method and post an answer if I find correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Малъ Скрылевъ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045870/ruby-and-rmagick-how-to-add-imagelist-to-imagelist-creating-list-of-the-lists#comment31652256_21045870) said, `ImageList` is based on `Enumerable`.
That means that you can just use `@il += @list_being_added`.